# return id from database after insert

Tags: database, insert, return, identifier, auto-increment

i have a php that responds to an ajax and inserts a row into database, this is the code

```
if($action == "insertCalendarEvents") {
        $calendar_group = $_GET["calendar_group"];
        $event_name = "'" . $_GET["event_name"] . "'";
        $event_datestart = "'" . $_GET["event_datestart"] . "'";
        $event_datestop = "'" . $_GET["event_datestop"] . "'";
        $event_timestart = $_GET["event_timestart"] != "" ? "'" . $_GET["event_timestart"] . "'" : "null";
        $event_timestop = $_GET["event_timestop"] != "" ? "'" . $_GET["event_timestop"] . "'" : "null";
        $event_info = "'" . $_GET["event_info"] . "'";

        require_once("connect.php");
        $query = "INSERT INTO calendar_events (calendar_group, event_name, event_datestart, event_datestop, event_timestart, event_timestop, event_info) VALUES (" . $calendar_group . ", " . $event_name . ", " . $event_datestart . ", " . $event_datestop . ", " . $event_timestart . ", " . $event_timestop . ", " . $event_info . ")";
        $result = pg_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$result)
            die("error 1"); // query error
    }
```

what i want to achieve it to make this code to return the id that the database auto-incremented and echo it back to the ajax function, the problem is that i cant get the last id because someone else might insert data after me and get the wrong id..
i would be rly happy to know if there is a workaround on this issue
Thanks in advance, Daniel!

EDIT: i want to add that i am using PostgreSQL as database, maybe it has a module to do that

Comment: Seems security is a futile endeavour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_value_of_a_SERIAL_insert.3F, it seems you can do queries like:

`INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('Blaise Pascal') RETURNING id`

I'm assuming you call pg_fetch_assoc() on the query resource and treat it like a SELECT?

Comment: Thank you very much, MichaelRushton! this is a huge step forward in my programming experience because everytime i code something related to database i encouter this problem :)

Answer (score -1):

use @@identity or scope_identity to get the the last index you inserted.

after your insert statement use `select @@identity`

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: can you be more specific pls.. i have the autoincremented field named event_id in the table calendar-events .. do i need to use SELECT @@event_id ?

Comment: in that case I think what you are looking for is currval()

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-use-currval-in-postgresql-to-get-the-last-inserted-id

Comment: yes i have tries currval and it works perfectly, the only thing im not 100% sure is what happens if more ppl add events in the same time in database, can currval return a wrong value than ? (and by wrong i mean not that value you should get, but the value of someone else)

Comment: if you followed that link I posted, you will see he says:

"No you are mistaken. currval() is "local" to your current connection. So there is no problem using it in a multi-user environment. That's the whole purpose of a sequence."

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-sequence.html

says, "Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if nextval has never been called for this sequence in this session.) Notice that because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer even if other sessions are executing nextval meanwhile."

Comment: also I don't use postegres, so you might want to use MichaelRushton's answer....RETURNING id

Comment: Thank you very much Timmerz. I have tried currval function too and it works as i expected. I see you said you dont use postgresql, is there a reason or you use a different one ? thank you again, i appreciate your help on this issue

Comment: I use sql server. that was my original answer. I'm not familiar with any other databases...glad you got it figured out.